# Windows Phone 7.5 phone call voice morphing

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to morph the voice of a outgoing call on Windows Phone 7/7.5?

It seems that we need 3 things:

1. Get audio samples from microphone;
2. Change the audio according to the expected voice effect;
3. Use our software to feed the call audio output (instead of the microphone directly).

I can only find information about 1. and 2., but 3. seems to be impossible.

Can you help me?

Comment: I think there is no such API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the current version of Windows Phone does not give you the capability to push your own audio through the phone radio or to insert any form of filter into that specific audio stream.